# When connecting to an API do I need an access token per each user using my application?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0

I'm connected to an API that provides information about cars based on their registration. According to the docs the api can provide both user specific data and general data about the registration supplied.

I am using the connection method which does require specific users data, and therefore does not require me to gain access to any specific users account.

On my end users will visit my application and enter a registration number which I will use to call the API and return all of the information about the car.

Am I right in my thinking that my application is essentially the 'user' as far as the api is concerned, and I will only need to use one access token. I can then use this access token to make multiple API calls (one for each user that searches on my application)?

Or will i need to set up an access token for each user that visits my application and treat them separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only your application making the API requests requires a token, unless the licence agreement/documentation of this car API says otherwise.

As far as your users are concerned, your application is just magically sourcing the registration info from its database.